# Android back navigation jumps straight to launcher

Tags: android

Whenever I press the back button from any activity in my app it jumps straight to the home screen. I was under the impression that I could set hierarchical parents using the manifest. Here is part of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.spicycheesecake.slidr" >

...

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   ...
    <activity
        android:name=".Tutorial"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    ...
</application>
```

Here is the code for the activity:

```
package com.spicycheesecake.slidr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tutorial extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutorialView)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.how_to_play)));
}
}
```

I am aware that `onBackPressed()` can be overridden, but I want to know why this isn't working.

My min sdk is 16 btw.

Comment: does it happen when you press back on tutorial activity?

Comment: @prudhvi yes that's the problem instead of backing out to the main menu it just closes the app

Comment: Can you post tutorial activity's code?

Comment: post some java code, what is the use of only manifest? onBackPressed(), can be override, you know.

Comment: From your Tutorial activity nothing seems to be wrong, I think you might be killing MainActivity some where in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have finished your activity when you called:

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will destroy the current activity and going to next. So when you press back it will go back to the last not destroyed.

Try to take out your line of code:

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't specified a parent activity you should be returned to the calling activity when you exit the previous one (and since you have one declared it should return you to it anyways). So the behavior of your app is really odd.

Could it be that you have overwritten `onBackPressed()` or `onDestroy()`?

EDIT: I mean the `onBackPressed()` and `onDestroy()` of your called activity, Tutorial in this case.

---

*Yes, this should be a comment, but I don't have the rep for it. Sorry*